# Order of Execution of Condition in a Where clause

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following statement with an Or condition. I am looking what would be the result when both conditions are true.

```
 var result = db.Result.FirstOrDefault(x=>(x.ID==50||x.ID==60)&&x.Name="XYZ");
```

In a case where I have a row in the result table where both the conditions are true, i.e; `x.ID=50` and `x.ID=60`. What would be the result of the query?

I have already tested to get the result in a test environment. But I wanted to make sure that the order of execution would always remain the same no matter what the size of the database is. As I have read that the where clause uses some sort of indexing for faster retrieval, what would be the course of execution of this statement.

The provided query is just a sample and the name ID has nothing to do with the unique identified of a table.

**Question**

How would the check be performed on the database? I would expect a result where it first checks if `ID ==50` and on failure check if `ID==60`. If this is my expected result, would the query given above achieve my task?

**Update after answer**

I find it necessary to give a more clearer example so that the question is more understandable. (If this update makes the existing answers invalid, I am really sorry)

```
 var result = db.result.firstordefault(x=>(x.foreignkeyid == someval|| foreignkeyid == 123)&& x.Name=="XYZ");
```

And my database sample

```
ID  foreignkeyid    Name
1      123          XYZ
2    somevalue      XYZ
3    anothervalue   XYZ
```

In this case when the query is executed the result would return the row with `ID==1` , but I want row wiht `ID==2` to be returned.

**Worst case attempt to achieve the result**

```
 var result = new Result();
 result =db.Result.firstordefault(x=>x.ID==somevalue&&x.name==xyz);
 if(result==null)
     var result = db.firstordefault(x=>x.ID ==123&& x.name==xyz);
```

Comment: Your query is checking for `Name` to be XYZ and `ID` to be 50 or 60. It is achieving what you require.

Comment: Yes. I missed i added that condition. I will edit the question to make it true as well.

Comment: There are chances where that particular condition is not satisfied. i even though of trying it this way `(foreignkeyid==somevalue &&name==XYZ)||(foreignkeyid==123&&name==XYZ)`. But this will also be equivalent to the above query i guess

Comment: For this kind of conditions its the optimizer which decides how the query to be planned, so if its found the the condition matching the record is early to be retrieved then it will get that one. So there is no hard and fast rule for this. You can however force the optimizer to retrieve the record using order by clause something as `order by ID desc limit 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this example of yours:

```
var result = db.result.firstordefault(x=>(x.foreignkeyid == someval|| foreignkeyid == 123)&& x.Name=="XYZ");
```

In which you want to prioritize the result where `fk = someval` (fk: foreign key), you can do the following:

```
db.set.OrderBy(x => x != someval) // false actually comes before true
      .ThenBy(x => x != val2ndPriority)
      .FirstOrDefault(x => (x.fk == someval ||
                            x.fk == val2ndPriority ||
                            x.fk == leastPriorityVal) &&
                           x.Name == "XYZ");
```

If you have a lot of "prioritized fk values", or if they are unknown at compile time, you can do:

```
var orderedEnum = db.set.OrderBy(x => x.Id);
foreach (var fk in fksByPriority)
    orderedEnum = orderedEnum.ThenBy(x => x != fk);
var result = orderedEnum.FirstOrDefault(x => fksByPriority.Contains(x.fk) &&
                                             x.Name == "XYZ");
```

---

**How I would prefer it to look like:**

Another different approach would be to get all possibly-relevant records and then run similar logic outside of the DB (your db Linq queries normally run smartly right inside the db):

```
var results = db.set.Where(x => x.Name == "XYZ" &&
                                fks.Contains(x.fk)).ToArray();
var highestPriorityResult =
    results.OrderBy(x => fksByPriority.IndexOf(x.fk)).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

*On a final note, I wish to say that your problem indicates a possibly flawed design. I can't imagine why you'd have this filtering-with-priority-foreign-key issue.*

Comment: If false comes before true, then my required row will be placed last while ordering right? because `someval` is the value of highest priority.

Comment: That's why I used `!=` instead of the logically correct `==` (just because its shorter than using `OrderByDescending`. Play with it and see what you get, you can always flip the comparison or call `.Reverse()` if needed.

Comment: Oh yeah. I missed it.. Oopss!!. I understand..  Thanks a lot.